# vlcj updating control bar (slider and timestamp) without causing frames to be skipped while playing

Tags: vlcj

I have a control bar in the player UI which has a play button, a slider and a timestamp (in the format `mm:ss/$video-duration` where mm being current minute, ss being current second and $video-duration is as its name states, duration of the video).

My code updates the slider position and the timestamp in MediaPlayerEventAdapter method `positionChanged(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, float newPosition)`. However, I believe because of the code inside that method, the video playback is skipping frames (the choppiness becomes particularly obvious when the video being played has a low frame rate).

```
@Override
public void positionChanged(MediaPlayer player, final float newPosition) {
   final float newTime = Math.round(newPosition*getVideoDuration());  
   slider.setValue(Math.round(newTime*VIDEO_FRAME_RATE));                            
   timeLabel.setText(formatTimeDisplay(newTime));
}
```

If positionChanged is not a good place to run this kind of code, what would you recommend me to try?

Comment: All media player events get delivered on background threads, so you are updating UI control state in a thread other than the UI thread. You need to use SwingUtilities#invokeLater.

Comment: I actually tried SwingUtilities#invokeLater but it didn't make a difference in my case.

Comment: Yes, it's not the solution to your particular problem, but nevertheless the point still stands.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason (hope the mistake I made can help others) -

my slider used a ChangeListener and in the `stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)` method, I was updating the video playback position (that was for when people drag the slider, I wanted the video playback position to get updated correspondingly) so essentially I created a loop-like situation where the slider's position got updated when the video playback position changed and when the slider's position changed, it's updating the video playback position as well.

I solved the problem by using a MouseMotionListener instead and implementing the `mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0)` method to take care of the scenario when people drag the slider to change the playback position.

Comment: The vlcj-player reference project also shows one way to properly implement the slider to get around the loop-like situation you describe. It is a bit non-obvious what you need to do, to be fair